# stellar.js - boostrapv4 - jquery 3.2.1 issue (no jquery migrate to use)

Tags: jquery, console.log, stellar.js

I'm trying to use stellar with bootstrap v4, jquery 3.2.1 but it returns error
"Uncaught TypeError: elem.getClientRects is not a function"

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/farkasimre/fo2pba5o/)

```
$.stellar({
  horizontalScrolling: false,
  verticalOffset: 40
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stellar is no more maintained and it's not compatible with newer jQuery 3. Try to use jQuery **2** and it should works.